# Draw polygon and detect if a marker is inside

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geolocation, latitude-longitude, bounding-box

I have these coordinates stored in a field of a database for drawing a polygon on a google map.  I want to detect if a marker is inside this polygon:

```
(37.15730677081955, -3.7892532348632812),
(37.13486648362684, -3.7593841552734375), 
(37.16059015678727, -3.7027359008789062)
```

Does anyone know how to get it?

Comment: take a look at google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation()  : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#poly

Comment: See [Point in Polygon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318812/google-map-is-a-lat-lng-within-a-polygon/13325478#13325478)

Answer (score 3):

You can use google map geometry library containsLocation() method with something like this:

```
for (var j=0; j < allMarkers.length; j++){
        for (var i=0; i < createdShapes.length; i++) {
            var latlong = allMarkers[j].getPosition();;
            if(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(latlong, createdShapes[i]) == true) {
                allMarkers[j].setOptions({
                    icon : "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_white.png",
                });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code written in Java to detect if a GPS Coordinate is inside a lat/long bounding box, it is mathematical, so it could probably be translated to other languages.

[Detecting whether a GPS coordinate falls within a polygon on a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287780/detecting-whether-a-gps-coordinate-falls-within-a-polygon-on-a-map)