# Mysql query within a given geographical area

Tags: mysql, sql, geo

A table in my database contains many postal addresses that also have longitude and latitude information like this:

Name ---- Street Address -------- Post Code ---- Longitude ---- Latitude

Fred ---- 11 Monarch Street ----- 4114 ---------- 57.317715 ---- 10.154355

Barney -- 4 Reign Street -------- 4114 ------------ 56.151112 ---- 10.087925

I have a given area (kml coordinates via google maps), defined like this:

```
        12.548740,55.694469,0.000000
        12.541320,55.687840,0.000000
        12.537410,55.690552,0.000000
        12.535310,55.694641,0.000000
        12.534499,55.695293,0.000000
        12.535787,55.696625,0.000000
        12.538100,55.696911,0.000000
        12.543890,55.697659,0.000000
        12.548740,55.694469,0.000000
```

What mysql query do I use to find addresses located within in the area?

Comment: maybe you should give more information like create table statments / more example data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any MySQL query for this.

In this [**Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318812/google-map-is-a-lat-lng-within-a-polygon/13325478#13325478) I use a PHP function to find if a point is in a polygon (4points).The function is based on C code [**Point in Polygon**](http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/) by *Darel Rex Finley*

You can use it for your 8 point polygon.

```
$polySides  = 8; //how many corners the polygon has
$polyX    =  array(12.548740,12.541320,12.537410,12.535310,12.534499,12.535787,12.538100,12.543890,12.548740);//horizontal coordinates of corners
$polyY    =  array(55.694469,55.687840,55.690552,55.694641,55.695293,55.696625,55.696911,55.697659,55.694469);//vertical coordinates of corners
$x = 12.548740; 
$y = 55.694469;//Inside
//$y = 12.528740;//Outside

function pointInPolygon($polySides,$polyX,$polyY,$x,$y) {
  $j = $polySides-1 ;
  $oddNodes = 0;
  for ($i=0; $i<$polySides; $i++) {
    if ($polyY[$i]<$y && $polyY[$j]>=$y 
 ||  $polyY[$j]<$y && $polyY[$i]>=$y) {
    if ($polyX[$i]+($y-$polyY[$i])/($polyY[$j]-$polyY[$i])*($polyX[$j]-$polyX[$i])<$x)    {
    $oddNodes=!$oddNodes; }}
   $j=$i; }

  return $oddNodes; }


 if (pointInPolygon($polySides,$polyX,$polyY,$x,$y)){
  echo "Is in polygon!";
}
else echo "Is not in polygon";
```

You can loop through your database inserting lat,lng into function.

If the database is large you can create a bounding box with north_west  and south_east 
coordinates to limit the data to be filtered by the function.

```
$sql = "SELECT lat,lng FROM `table` WHERE (lng BETWEEN '$west_lng' AND '$east_lng') AND (lat BETWEEN '$north_lat' AND '$south_lat')";
```

The other solution is to use [**mysql spatial extension**](http://howto-use-mysql-spatial-ext.blogspot.co.uk/)

Comment: Thank you very much David, that is a beautiful piece of code. I am using php and mysql. I have a large table with some 12,000 addresses so I would like to use the bounding box. How do I do that?

Comment: Query not formated for PDO But parameters can be hard coded.I leave you to work out corners of box.