# How to check if a lat/long coordinate exists or doesn't exist inside a polygon - PHP

Tags: php, google-maps, geolocation, geocoding

I want to write some code in PHP that will check a single lat/long co-ordinate against the co-ordinates of a polygon.  And return true or false whether it exists inside the polygon.

e.g. I created a polygon here..
http://www.geocodezip.com/polygonTool.asp

0: 53.34545,-6.255083
1: 53.340121,-6.239033
2: 53.338788,-6.238947
3: 53.337405,-6.240492
4: 53.334227,-6.245642
5: 53.332074,-6.252937
6: 53.330024,-6.264353
7: 53.333766,-6.264868
8: 53.33761,-6.265812
9: 53.338583,-6.266155
10: 53.341607,-6.265383
11: 53.342683,-6.264439
12: 53.344067,-6.264696
13: 53.344733,-6.259632

And I have a users location as...
53.338839, -6.249386 (Which does exist inside this polygon).

Is there a simple way of verifying that this is inside or outside the polygon?

Comment: Loop through your array of polygon points and ensure your passed in value doesn't exceed them in any one direction

Comment: Why is this tagged google-maps-api-3?  That is javascript on the client, PHP is on the server.

Answer (score 1):

One way to find if a point is in a polygon is to count how many times a line drawn from the point (in any direction) intersects with the polygon boundary. If they intersect an even number of times, then the point is outside.

The following PHP code requires 2 arrays $polyX = array of the longitude points of the polygon. Repeat the first point to close the polygon. $polyy = array of the latitude points of the polygon,

```
$polySides  = 13; //how many corners the polygon has
$polyX = array(53.34545,53.340121,53.338788,53.337405,53.334227,53.332074,53.330024,53.333766,53.33761,53.338583,53.341607,53.342683,53.344067,53.344733,53.34545);
$polyY = array(6.255083,-6.239033,-6.238947,-6.240492,-6.245642,-6.252937,-6.264353,-6.264868,-6.265812,-6.266155,-6.265383,-6.264439,-6.264696,-6.259632,6.255083);
$x =53.338839;//your coordinates
$y =-6.249386;


function pointInPolygon($polySides,$polyX,$polyY,$x,$y) {
  $j = $polySides-1 ;
  $oddNodes = 0;
  for ($i=0; $i<$polySides; $i++) {
    if ($polyY[$i]<$y && $polyY[$j]>=$y 
 ||  $polyY[$j]<$y && $polyY[$i]>=$y) {
    if ($polyX[$i]+($y-$polyY[$i])/($polyY[$j]-$polyY[$i])*($polyX[$j]-$polyX[$i])<$x)    {
    $oddNodes=!$oddNodes; }}
   $j=$i; }

  return $oddNodes; }


 if (pointInPolygon($polySides,$polyX,$polyY,$x,$y)){
  echo "Is in polygon!";
}
else echo "Is not in polygon";
```

SEE [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318812/google-map-is-a-lat-lng-within-a-polygon/13325478#13325478) for javascript implementation.

Answer (score 0):

From my [Geodetic classes](https://github.com/MarkBaker/PHPGeodetic), the basic function is:

```
function isInRegion(Geodetic_LatLong $position)
{
    $latitude = $position->getLatitude()->getValue();
    $longitude = $position->getLongitude()->getValue();
    $perimeterNodeCount = count($this->_nodePoints);
    $jIndex = $perimeterNodeCount - 1 ;
    $oddNodes = FALSE;
    for ($iIndex = 0; $iIndex < $perimeterNodeCount; ++$iIndex) {
        $iLatitude = $this->_nodePoints[$iIndex]->getLatitude()->getValue();
        $jLatitude = $this->_nodePoints[$jIndex]->getLatitude()->getValue();
        if (($iLatitude < $latitude && $jLatitude >= $latitude) ||
            ($jLatitude < $latitude && $iLatitude >= $latitude)) {
            $iLongitude = $this->_nodePoints[$iIndex]->getLongitude()->getValue();
            $jLongitude = $this->_nodePoints[$jIndex]->getLongitude()->getValue();
            if ($iLongitude +
                ($latitude - $iLatitude) /
                ($jLatitude - $iLatitude) * ($jLongitude - $iLongitude) < $longitude) {
                $oddNodes = !$oddNodes;
            }
        }
        $jIndex = $iIndex;
    }
    return $oddNodes;
}
```

Comment: Can it be as simple as this...
"Loop through your array of polygon points and ensure your passed in value doesn't exceed them in any one direction"
As per Varedis comment above

Comment: If you consider the actual algorithm being executed, it's basically the same as that described in David Strachan's answer: count how many times a line drawn from the point (in any direction) intersects with the polygon boundary, and if they intersect an even number of times, then the point is outside the polygon